# New install but what version

Tags: webserver

I want to convert my current WIN2003 server to Ubuntu and then install Apache.  I use this machine for a web server for several sites. This is an X86 machine.

My questions is do I install Ubuntu desktop or Ubuntu Server?

thanks

Comment: Server does not have a GUI. That's main difference.

Comment: the term "version" generally refers to ubuntu 14.04, 14.10, etc. You could use another word, but better to edit this to e.g. "new install: should i use ubuntu desktop or ubuntu server?" There isn't afaik a good standard word. I'd say "distribution," but that will confuse people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, it doesn't really matter. The only difference between them will probably be which packages are preinstalled. E.g. desktop will have unity installed by default. You could use desktop install cd, and then remove all the desktop packages and you'd have a perfectly good server machine.

Then again, having the desktop installed or running doesn't actually interfere the machine's ability to be a server, except insofar as it consumes resources.

Ubuntu server (which I haven't used in forever) probably already has all the stuff you would probably want to remove taken out already, but then again maybe not. Like I said, it doesn't really matter. You can always use apt to add what you want and remove what you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu server would be a better option , as far as i know ubuntu server will have pre installed packages of apache2 and many other required packages